# Style every 4th alternative odd/even nth-child(2n) without jquery

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Current Scenario

[image]

What I want

[image]

Please see following snippet to edit. Hope this will help you.

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 400px;
}
li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: yellow;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

I need pure CSS solution if possible.

Comment: Using of classes is not option, i guess?

Comment: No, I can solve it using classes or bunch of css selectors, but I want clean solution. I know this is not easy, as I'm working on it since 4 days :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially you're working with repeating groups with an offset of 8, so you can use this:

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 400px;
}
li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
}
li:nth-child(8n+2), li:nth-child(8n+4), li:nth-child(8n+5), li:nth-child(8n+7) {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great bro, really much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah just did this and saw basically same answer - I used 8n and subtracted.

```css
ul {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FF8E00;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 45px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #777;
}
li:nth-child(odd),
li:nth-child(8n),
li:nth-child(8n - 2) {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
li:nth-child(8n - 3),
li:nth-child(8n - 1) {
  background-color: #FF8E00;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li></ul>
```